# Detecting precompiled headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way for the preprocessor to detect if the code in current
translation unit uses(or is creating) precompiled headers?

 --- 
The actual problem I'm facing right now is that I'm on a project that is
abusing PCH by precompiling virtually all header files. 
That means there is none of
the clear dependency management you can get from #includes and the compile times is awful.
Practically every change will trigger a full rebuild.
The application is way to big to just fix it in one go, and some of the old guys refuses
to belive that precompiling everyting is bad in any way. I will have to prove it first.
So I must do it step by step and make sure my changes does not affect
code that is compiled the old PCH way.
My plan is to do ifdef out the PCH.h and work on the non PCH version whenever I have some time to spare.

```
#ifdef USES_PCH
#include "PCH.h"
#elif
// include only whats needed
#endif
```

I would like to avoid defining USES_PCH at command line and manually keep it in
sync with /Y that, besides from not being very elegant, would be a pain. There is a lot of configurations
and modules to juggle with and a lot of files that don't follow project defaults.

Comment: Surely the preprocessor already knows whether it's supposed to be generating or using precompiled headers. It doesn't need to *detect* anything. Did you instead mean to ask whether the *code being processed* can detect it, like with some `ifdef` command?

Comment: Yes, I want to do a #ifdef __USES_PCH or something similar

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve with this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23265430/1889329) addresses part of your question. Using those compiler switches you can remove the `#include "PCH.h"` directive, and create two configurations: One that does use precompiled headers (with the appropriate `/FI` switch), and a second configuration to use for cleanup.

Answer (score 3):

If Visual C++ defined a constant to indicate whether precompiled headers were in use, it would probably be listed in [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). And it's not documented there, so it probably doesn't exist. (If it does exist, it's probably undocumented and may change in a future version.)

Comment: Yes I know the is no official macro. If there was one I wouldn't have to ask here.
I hoped that someone knew of some indirect way of figuring it out anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This will not work, when using precompiled headers in Visual C++, you cannot even have any code before  including a precompiled header.  I was trying to do something similar, when I came across your question.  After a little trial and error, I have found that there can be no code prior to the #include directive for the precompiled header when using the /Yu compiler option.

```
#ifdef USES_PCH 
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
```

result: fatal error C1020: unexpected #endif

Comment: I think #ifdef before precompiled header does work in VS2015.

Comment: @ShitalShah, it doesn't work for me in VS2015. The above code still produces a C1020 error when the file is set to use a PCH (/Yu option).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it can't, but there are some heuristics: VC++ uses StdAfx.h, Borland uses #pragma hdrstop, etc.

Comment: VC++ only uses StdAfx.h if you work with the default project settings, you can change that at any time.

Comment: I for one change it to something unique for each vcproj, but I expect that many projects just go with the defaults.