# C++ Compiler Macro for Status of "Use Precompiled Headers"

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, macros

It there a predefined c++ compiler macro that I can use to tell, whether a file is compiled with "Use Precompiled Headers", "Create Precompiled Headers", "Dont Use Precompiled Headers"?

See @IronMensan 's answer for the purpose of such a macro!

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by testing for this property?

Comment: Precompiled headers are not part of standard C++, so you'll need to be more specific.  That said, there is no way you can do anything useful with the information should it be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything, though I certainly understand the desire for one.  Whenever I have to build my cross-platform library on a system that dozen't support PCH, it takes forever since a lot of files are pulling in way more than they really need and it would be nice to trim that out.  Unfortunately I can't because of how Visual Studio handles PCH.  Namely that the inclusion of the PCH must be the first non-comment line of the file.  From the way you worded your question, I suspect that you are also working with Visual Studio.

I am not sure if this will work for you but you could try something like this:

```
#include MY_PCH_FILE
```

And use
    /DMY_PCH_FILE="myfile.h"

on the command line to control what the first include file is.  After that you have full control over what gets included and proper header guards along with the optimization in most modern compilers to detect header guards could reduce build times.  You can change the definition of the macro for individual file in the build settings of your project, in a similar manor to how you can change the PCH settings for each file.

Though I must admit that I am not sure what you are trying to do and I suspect this is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio/MSC does not provide a predefined macro that carries the setting of the `/Y[-cdu]` compiler switch for inspection from source code.

However, there is a solution to the problem you are trying to solve, i.e. controlling whether or not the first non-comment line of a source file should be `#include "<my pch.h>"`: MSC offers the [/FI (Name Forced Include File)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) compiler switch.

> This option has the same effect as specifying the file with double quotation marks in an #include directive on the first line of every source file specified on the command line [...]

This compiler switch can either be specified on the compiler's command line, or on a per-project basis through the IDE's GUI (Project -> Properties: C/C++ -> Advanced: Forced Include File).

With a combination of the `/Y[-cdu]` and `/FI` compiler switches you can both control the use and meet the requirements for using precompiled headers, from outside the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can create manualy yourself the macro. 
You can define **USE_PRECOMPILEDHDR** and **FORCED_INCLUDEHDR** when you use precompilation like this

```
#if USE_PRECOMPILEDHDR
    #ifndef FORCED_INCLUDEHDR
        #include "stdafx.h"
    #endif
#else 
    //..manualy include all your headers
#endif
```

But as other saying, except if you change for another compiler, you have no reason to use guards for this.

Answer (score -1):

This feature is unlikely to exist. The whole point of precompiled headers is that the headers will be compiled with *exactly the same* compiler options as when compiling for real. If the compiler were to offer a way for your code to tell the difference, then you could make your code behave differently (at a preprocessor level) depending on whether the compiler is precompiling or actually compiling.

Comment: Yep, makes no sense to have such a feature, or want one.

Comment: Please see @IronMensan 's answer for the sense

Comment: This answer does not address the question. This is not about trying to deduce, whether code is compiled to produce a precompiled header or not. This is about whether or not a particular option is set by the build system.

Answer (score -3):

If you're looking to include header files based on whether or not precompiled headers are enabled, you should use an [Include Guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) instead.

Comment: Can you explain more on how to do that?

Comment: But how would I get some MACRO defined or not defined, just by setting the compiler setting for precompiled headers?

Comment: There's no way to do that, as other people have said. Can you explain more about why you need a macro defined if precompiled headers are enabled?